# Cannot get internet on specific wifi's

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, internet

I have recently installed PopOS 19.10 on my Dell XPS 9570, but i have run into a problem, where i cannot connect to the internet on my wifi.

The weird thing is i can connect to the internet sharing of my phone and some wifis, but most of them i just receive a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG on chrome. So it seems i have a DNS error, but i have tried adding Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) both in the GUI and to the /etc/resolve.conf file, but it doesn't help.

I will now provide some logs. I have run this script, from this answer (http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/44179):

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info
```

Which results in this:

On wifi i have internet: https://pastebin.com/JWHPgtTf

On Wifi where i don't have internet: https://pastebin.com/YSaY0xm6

I have searched for days how to fix this issue, but i have not yet found an answer which could help me.

Things i have tried:

- Restarting NetworkManager
- Restarting systemd-resolved
- Adding google nameservers to the /etc/resolve.conf
- Using NetworkManager and dnsmasq
- Using the resolve.conf file from NetworkManager

Comment: I don't know the equivalent for Ubuntu, on newer openSUSE releases `netconfig update -f` has helped many times. Maybe there's a similar command that achieves the same thing.

Comment: The machine seems to be far too away from the AP. However, I do fail to understand how debugging wifi problems is on topic here. The question is also overly broad.

Comment: I suspect that it is some sort of network driver issue or DNS issue, that causes the error because it works on some wifis, and i have tried to stand right beside the router. Moreover it works perfectly in Windows.